# Joining multiple tables into one de-normalized table

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I'm looking to join multiple tables to get a resultant single de-normalized table. Below is one such scenario where I have 2 tables and an expected resultant table.

Table 1:

```
id       From Date                  To Date                  User
AA12345  02-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM    08-Jan-2017 11:59:59 PM  LL7R
AA12345  09-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM    14-Feb-2017 11:59:59 PM  AT3B
AA12345  15-Feb-2017 12:00:00 AM    31-Dec-3030 11:59:59 PM  UJ5G
```

Table 2:

```
id                                                           Associated id
AA12345  06-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM    23-Jan-2017 11:59:59 AM  AA12345, AA234567
AA12345  24-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM    31-Dec-3030 11:59:59 PM  AA12345, AA234567, AB56789
```

Notice that id values are same in both tables. Consider these as event tables where there are different events happening at various time periods.
So the resultant final table should have all the events without any overlaps between From and To dates. 
In case there is an overlap between 'From Date' and 'To Date' as you see in this example ('To Date' of Table 1's 1st record is greater than 'From Date' of Table 2's 1st record), result table's 'To Date' is updated based on nearest next date minus 1 second (In this case, 06-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM minus 1 second).

Result:

```
Dnorm    From Date                  To Date                  User   Associated id
AA12345  02-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM    05-Jan-2017 11:59:59 PM  LL7R   
AA12345  06-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM    08-Jan-2017 11:59:59 PM  LL7R   AA12345, AA234567
AA12345  09-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM    23-Jan-2017 11:59:59 AM  AT3B   AA12345, AA234567
AA12345  24-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM    14-Feb-2017 11:59:59 PM  AT3B   AA12345, AA234567, AB56789
AA12345  15-Feb-2017 12:00:00 AM    31-Dec-3030 11:59:59 PM  UJ5G   AA12345, AA234567, AB56789
```

How do we achieve this effectively?

Comment: How do you get 5-Jan-2017 in first row of the result?

Comment: I need a 'To date' for the first record. So its an offset from the 2nd record's 'From date'

Comment: How do you calculate 5-Jan-2017 from Table 1 & Table 2? I assume Result is a function of Table 1 & Table 2.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain in details, what are the business rules. Also please include specific language tag (Python or Scala not both).

Comment: @jp_data_analysis Yes, updated the question with little more details. Hope this clarifies. 5-Jan-2017 is calculated from table 2's From Date.

Comment: @user8371915 updated.

Comment: @MaheshShankar, can you explain why 3rd row has `23-Jan-2017 11:59:59 AM` ?

Comment: Goal is to get non - overlapping date ranges with order. 23-Jan-2017 11:59:59 AM is the next date value after 09-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 4):

So what you want is called **outer join** and there are four types of this operation depending on the table which has the priority if the values in columns doesn't match.

In the example we have 2 tables

Table1

```
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+
|    id|           From Date|             To Date|User|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+
|AA1111|02-Jan-2017 12:00...|08-Jan-2017 11:59...|LL7R|
|AA1112|09-Jan-2017 12:00...|14-Feb-2017 11:59...|AT3B|
|AA1113|15-Feb-2017 12:00...|31-Dec-3030 11:59...|UJ5G|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+
```

Table2

```
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    id|           From Date|             To Date|       Associated id|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|AA1111|03-Jan-2017 12:00...|08-Jan-2017 11:59...|           [AA12345]|
|AA1112|10-Jan-2017 12:00...|14-Feb-2017 11:59...|           [AA12345]|
|AA1113|16-Feb-2017 12:00...|30-Dec-3030 11:59...|           [AA12345]|
|AA1114|24-Jan-2017 12:00...|31-Dec-3030 11:59...|[AA12345, AA23456...|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Note that the first row in *Table 2* not only have the same `id` as the first row in the *Table 1* but also same `From Date` and `To Date` values. Second row on the other hand have the same `id` and `To Date` but different `From Date`. Third row only has the same `id` and forth row is completely different. For the sake of simplicity we'll assume that this combinations cover all the variations in your data.

Now to the different types of **joins**

## Full outer join

Full outer join will just create additional rows if the all three values are not exactly the same. It will break the IDs so use caution.

```
val dfFullOuter =
    table1
    .join( table2, Seq( "id", "From Date", "To Date" ), "outer" )
```

Result

```
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+
|    id|           From Date|             To Date|User|       Associated id|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+
|AA1112|09-Jan-2017 12:00...|14-Feb-2017 11:59...|AT3B|                null|
|AA1113|15-Feb-2017 12:00...|31-Dec-3030 11:59...|UJ5G|                null|
|AA1114|24-Jan-2017 12:00...|31-Dec-3030 11:59...|null|[AA12345, AA23456...|
|AA1111|02-Jan-2017 12:00...|08-Jan-2017 11:59...|LL7R|           [AA12345]|
|AA1113|16-Feb-2017 12:00...|30-Dec-3030 11:59...|null|           [AA12345]|
|AA1112|10-Jan-2017 12:00...|14-Feb-2017 11:59...|null|           [AA12345]|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+
```

As you can see the row with `id` **AA1111** is merged successfully because there are no conflicting values. Other rows are just copied. This method is recommended only if you are **absolutely** confident that values in columns `To Date` and `From Date` will be the same for the rows with the same `id`.

You can also merge by `id` only and then decide to what table you want to give a priority. In this example priority is given to *Table 2*

```
val dfFullOuterManual =
    table1
    .join( table2, Seq( "id" ), "outer" )
    .drop( table1( "From Date" ) )
    .drop( table1( "To Date" ) )
```

Result

```
+------+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    id|User|           From Date|             To Date|       Associated id|
+------+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|AA1112|AT3B|10-Jan-2017 12:00...|14-Feb-2017 11:59...|           [AA12345]|
|AA1111|LL7R|02-Jan-2017 12:00...|08-Jan-2017 11:59...|           [AA12345]|
|AA1114|null|24-Jan-2017 12:00...|31-Dec-3030 11:59...|[AA12345, AA23456...|
|AA1113|UJ5G|16-Feb-2017 12:00...|30-Dec-3030 11:59...|           [AA12345]|
+------+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

## Left outer join

Left outer join will give priority to the values in *Table 1* and even when there is only one conflict it will use all the values from that table. Note that `Associated id` values for conflicting rows are **nulled** because there is no such column in *Table 1*. Also the row with `id` **AA1114** will not be copied.

```
val dfLeftOuter =
    table1
    .join( table2, Seq( "id", "From Date", "To Date" ), "left_outer" )
```

Result

```
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+-------------+
|    id|           From Date|             To Date|User|Associated id|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+-------------+
|AA1111|02-Jan-2017 12:00...|08-Jan-2017 11:59...|LL7R|    [AA12345]|
|AA1112|09-Jan-2017 12:00...|14-Feb-2017 11:59...|AT3B|         null|
|AA1113|15-Feb-2017 12:00...|31-Dec-3030 11:59...|UJ5G|         null|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+-------------+
```

We resolved the conflict in columns `From Date` and `To Date` and now it's time to get missing `Associated id` values. To do that we need to merge the previous result with selected values from *Table 2*.

```
val dfLeftOuterFinal =
    dfLeftOuter
    .join( table2.select( "id", "Associated id" ) , Seq( "id" ) )
    .drop( dfLeftOuter( "Associated id" ) )
```

Note that dropping original `Associated id` columns is necessary because it's taken from *Table 1* and is mostly **null**.

Final result

```
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+-------------+
|    id|           From Date|             To Date|User|Associated id|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+-------------+
|AA1111|02-Jan-2017 12:00...|08-Jan-2017 11:59...|LL7R|    [AA12345]|
|AA1112|09-Jan-2017 12:00...|14-Feb-2017 11:59...|AT3B|    [AA12345]|
|AA1113|15-Feb-2017 12:00...|31-Dec-3030 11:59...|UJ5G|    [AA12345]|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+-------------+
```

## Right outer join

Right outer join will give priority to the data in *Table 2* and will add the completely different row (**AA1114**) to the resulting table. Note that `User` values for conflicting rows are **nulled** because there is no such column in *Table 2*.

```
val dfRightOuter =
    table1
    .join( table2, Seq( "id", "From Date", "To Date" ), "right_outer" )
```

Result

```
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+
|    id|           From Date|             To Date|User|       Associated id|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+
|AA1111|02-Jan-2017 12:00...|08-Jan-2017 11:59...|LL7R|           [AA12345]|
|AA1112|10-Jan-2017 12:00...|14-Feb-2017 11:59...|null|           [AA12345]|
|AA1113|16-Feb-2017 12:00...|30-Dec-3030 11:59...|null|           [AA12345]|
|AA1114|24-Jan-2017 12:00...|31-Dec-3030 11:59...|null|[AA12345, AA23456...|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+
```

As with left outer join we have to retrieve missing values. Now it's `User`

```
val dfRightOuterFinal =
    dfRightOuter
    .join( table1.select( "id", "User" ) , Seq( "id" ) )
    .drop( dfRightOuter( "User" ) )
```

Final result

```
+------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+----+
|    id|           From Date|             To Date|Associated id|User|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+----+
|AA1111|02-Jan-2017 12:00...|08-Jan-2017 11:59...|    [AA12345]|LL7R|
|AA1112|10-Jan-2017 12:00...|14-Feb-2017 11:59...|    [AA12345]|AT3B|
|AA1113|16-Feb-2017 12:00...|30-Dec-3030 11:59...|    [AA12345]|UJ5G|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+----+
```

Note that row with `id` **A1114** is gone because there is no `User` value for it.

## Final thoughts

Depending on the data priority you can play with this combinations for other columns. As you can see these types of joins are also used to handle gaps in data according to your intentions.

My full test bench code

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object Main {

    def main( args: Array[ String ] ): Unit = {

        val spark =
            SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName( "SO" )
            .master( "local[*]" )
            .config( "spark.driver.host", "localhost" )
            .getOrCreate()

        import spark.implicits._

        val table1Data = Seq(
            ( "AA1111", "02-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM", "08-Jan-2017 11:59:59 PM", "LL7R" ),
            ( "AA1112", "09-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM", "14-Feb-2017 11:59:59 PM", "AT3B" ),
            ( "AA1113", "15-Feb-2017 12:00:00 AM", "31-Dec-3030 11:59:59 PM", "UJ5G" )
        )

        val table1 =
            table1Data
            .toDF( "id", "From Date", "To Date", "User" )

        val table2Data = Seq(
            ( "AA1111", "02-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM", "08-Jan-2017 11:59:59 PM", Seq( "AA12345" ) ),
            ( "AA1112", "10-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM", "14-Feb-2017 11:59:59 PM", Seq( "AA12345" ) ),
            ( "AA1113", "16-Feb-2017 12:00:00 AM", "30-Dec-3030 11:59:59 PM", Seq( "AA12345" ) ),
            ( "AA1114", "24-Jan-2017 12:00:00 AM", "31-Dec-3030 11:59:59 PM", Seq( "AA12345", "AA234567", "AB56789" ) )
        )

        val table2 =
            table2Data
            .toDF( "id", "From Date", "To Date", "Associated id" )

        val dfFullOuter =
            table1
            .join( table2, Seq( "id", "From Date", "To Date" ), "outer" )

        val dfFullOuterManual = 
            table1
            .join( table2, Seq( "id" ), "outer" )
            .drop( table1( "From Date" ) )
            .drop( table1( "To Date" ) )

        val dfLeftOuter =
            table1
            .join( table2, Seq( "id", "From Date", "To Date" ), "left_outer" )

        val dfLeftOuterFinal =
            dfLeftOuter
            .join( table2.select( "id", "Associated id" ) , Seq( "id" ) )
            .drop( dfLeftOuter( "Associated id" ) )

        val dfRightOuter =
            table1
            .join( table2, Seq( "id", "From Date", "To Date" ), "right_outer" )

        val dfRightOuterFinal =
            dfRightOuter
            .join( table1.select( "id", "User" ) , Seq( "id" ) )
            .drop( dfRightOuter( "User" ) )

        spark.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for your efforts :)  @Dennis Tsoi Thanks for taking time and helping the community.

Comment: I just realised that there is another way to handle that and updated the answer.